# Inserting rows to interleaved tables in a single transaction

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

I have table hierarchy as follows

```
Table A - Root level
     Table B - Child of A
     Table C - Child of A
     Table D - Child of A
```

I am inserting all the related rows in a single Commit transaction. The order of the insert statements are as follows. Thus, the insert statement to the root table is last in the list. When in this case, I am getting the error `"Row [*******] in table A was already created in this transaction.`

```
   -- Insert  B
   -- Insert  C
   -- Insert  D
   -- Insert  A
```

I had to change the insert order in such a way that, the Root Table row is first in the list to get rid of the error.

Obviously, it suggests that the order of insert statements in a Commit statement is important especially with the interleaved tables. However, I couldn't find this in any documents. Can someone please point me if this is documented somewhere.?

Comment: You are right, the parent record must be inserted first.

Looks like we don't explicitly tell that in the documentation, we are going to fix this, thanks!